# How to execute the command from another shell in python?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to run some command which opens another shell, where I can type specific commands. In that shell I'd like to run another command in a loop.
To be more specific - in my example it looks like this:

```
> openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.10:10000 ### this is the first command
CONNECTED(00000003) ### some output
(...)
### now i'd like to type 'R' in a loop (R means renegotiate)
```

What's the best way to do that? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I think you're looking for subprocess https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With subprocess, like this.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'ls -la' 
subprocess.call(cmd.split(), shell=False)
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
import subprocess

connect = 'openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.10:10000' 
subprocess.call(connect.split(), shell=False)

while (something):
    subprocess.call('R', shell=False)
```